# Rotate CGRect property of a CCSprite ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cgrect

I have a sublclass of a CCSprite that rotates throughout the game and there is a shield that has to rotate around the sprite according to the sprite's rotation. So if the sprite's rotation is 75 degrees there should be a CGRect located at 75 degrees. The dimensions of the CGRect are subordinate as it almost resembles a square.

What I did is:

- I subclassed CCSprite and added a property called shieldArea.
- Upon initialization I set this rect to be

  ```
  self.shieldArea = CGRectMake(self.position.x-30, self.position.y, 8, 10);
  ```
- Then I rotate the sprite itself, however, the rect stays at its initial position.

I hoped that the CGrect would be affected by the rotation, but I kind of expected it not to affect it, of course, why should it ? So, my question is, how do I rotate a CGRect at all ? Or do I have to add a new CGRect all the time ?

Side notes: I do not want to use Box2d or anything the like. I handle collision detection myself.

Comment: If collision detection is done for you in cocos2d why roll your own?  This issue would go away using Box2d.

Comment: @Hyperbole : How accurate is collision detection in Box2d and what do I have to do to use it ?

Comment: Ray Wenderlich has a tutorial on collision detection and I have no idea what is happening in most of his Box2d related code. So that is pretty much my problem.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, I added more code in my answer to account for a missing anchor point, that might help.  Otherwise, I can't really help you with the Box2d stuff without a more specific question.  Sorry--

Comment: nope. No success whatsoever :( .

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`CGAffineTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000946)?

Something like this:

```
float centerX = myOldRect.origin.x + (myOldRect.size.width / 2.0);
float centerY = myOldRect.origin.y + (myOldRect.size.height / 2.0);

CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(someAngleInRadians);
CGAffineTransform moveAnchor = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(centerX, centerY);

CGAffineTransform centeredRotation = CGAffineTransformConcat(moveAnchor, rotation);

CGRect rotatedRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(myOldRect, centeredRotation);
```

Note, this is NOT tested.  Use at your own risk :p

Comment: If i draw the CGRect it gets gigantic and not at all what I need. I do not know if I do something wrong, but I think I do not. I use radians and assign the result of the transformation to my 'self.shieldArea'.